# Is there any Android Bluetooth Broadcast method readily available?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there any function to broadcast a message using Bluetooth in android?

I couldnt find such a function. So I retrieved the near by devices by using the follwing code

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

Can I simply send a message to each device found, without any prior connection but paired?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth before version 4.0 doesn't have a usable way of broadcasting data. If you have a list of nearby devices and they are already paired, you can open a connection to all of them and send data.

With Bluetooth Low Energy, supported only by the iPhone 4S and probably the next Google phone, you could have "advertisements" that contain data.